# emacs python mode, python-send-buffer/string/region gives "Invalid Syntax" error

Tags: python, macos, emacs

I have used python-mode's python-send-buffer(and similar ones) successfully in a different system in the past.

I don't get why I'm getting error here. And worse, googling doesn't help..
Below is the output when I try sending "from math import sqrt" to *Python* by C-c C-r

```
>>> emacs.eexecfile("/var/folders/qy/qyS-532mGoWXHKmsdumelk+++TI/-Tmp-/py1850AbJ")
  File "/var/folders/qy/qyS-532mGoWXHKmsdumelk+++TI/-Tmp-/py1850AbJ", line 1
    from math import sqrt
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My system is mac snowleopard and emacs 23.3.1, python 2.6.1

http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.emacs.help/browse_thread/thread/125d72278d513bea?pli=1 talks about ^M .
I added the proposed solution to my .emacs but no difference

```
 (add-to-list 'process-coding-system-alist 
      '("python" cp1251-unix . cp1251-unix))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message the problem is that you have inserted some whitespace in front of the line: the circumflex is pointing at a blank space. Indentation is significant in Python, you cannot start a script with an indented line.

Comment: It was file saved for windows, and had problem running in mac.
changed the encoding via C-x RET f to undecided-unix.